# Javascript syntax problem - line with ` works but with ' not, why?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I do have a syntax problem with PHP:

If I type this in Visual Studio Code there are no issues on this line:

```
html += `<a href="php/get-download.php?&link=${encodeURIComponent(input_URL)}" target="_blank"></a>`;
```

But it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11, which gives the error:

> Message: Invalid characters

Code:

```
html += '<a href="php/get-download.php?&link=' + 
${encodeURIComponent(input_URL)} + '" target="_blank"></a>`;
```

Visual Studio Code doesn't accept this line of code as there is a Syntax problem.

> Error: `$` => `';'` expected
>   `;` => `Unterminated string literal.`

I found out that this have to do with `[Template-Strings][1]` but how can I avoid this syntax? How can I format this correctly so that it works also on Internet Explorer?

Comment: You're trying to concatenate strings with the JS/C+ method of `+`; you want dots. Far as I can tell; you tagged as "php".

Comment: You also have a tick at the end of that.

Comment: Please make an example of a working line. Im trying to figure out a correct syntax since a few hours....

Comment: OK I have edited my quesiton. Was a mistake...

Answer (score 0):

```
html += '<a href="php/get-download.php?&link=' + ${encodeURIComponent(input_URL)} + '" target="_blank"></a>';
```

You have ` instead of ' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility) are just not supported by any version of Internet Explorer - see the big red X in the IE column.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are good but not complete. 
(Sorry cant comment so i will answer)

You should use https://caniuse.com when implementing something kinda new to check its support.

In your case you should switch to the old school string building:

```
html += '<a href="php/get-download.php?&link=' + encodeURIComponent(input_URL) + '" target="_blank">link</a>';
```

No need to use ${}.